# how to empty nearest table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code. When I click on click1 I need to empty the table that is in next div. is it possible to empty that table by using closest siblings using jquery.

i am using

```
obj = $(this);
obj.siblings('table').empty();


 <div>
    <div class="dropdown busBook">
              <a class="triggerBook listItemBook" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">Click here</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                <li><a class="emptytable"   href="javascript:void(0)" >click1</a></li>
                <li><a class="emptytable" id="Tele"  href="javascript:void(0)">click2</a></li>
                <li><a class="emptytable" "  href="javascript:void(0)">click3</a></li>
              </ul>

              <form>
              <input type="hidden" value="<%= user.id %>" i name="user_id" title="Consulting"  />
              </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row hide">

          <div class="col-md-12"> 

            <div class="bookhere">
              <div id="table-wrapper"><div id="table-scroll">  
              <a class="next pull-right" id='next_id' href="#">next</a>
              <input type="hidden" value="<%= user.id %>" name="user_id" />
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <input type="hidden" value="<%= Date.today + 7.days %>"  name="next" />
              <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" id='table_id'>
                  <tr>
                    <% (Date.today..Date.today + 8.days).first(7).each do |display| %>
                      <th><%= display.strftime("%a") %>(<%= display.strftime("%d/%m") %>)</th>
                    <% end %>
                  </tr>
                 <tr><td>Date here</td></tr>
              </table>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What about clicking on `click2` and `click3`? Do you want to empty the table as well?

Comment: Yes. If i click on clcik2 and click3 also  empty the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a').closest('.div_class_name').siblings('table').empty();
```

Try like this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your HTML markup, you can use:

```
$('a.emptytable').closest('div.dropdown').parent().next().find('table').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
$(".emptytable" ).click(function() {
      $(.dropdown).parent().next().find('table').empty();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you.

```
     $(function() {
       $('#myDiv1').next('div').children().html('');    
  });
```

HTML for this above function is

```
<div id="myDiv1">
  <table>
     <tr>
       <td>1</td><td>Sample Data</td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>2</td><td>Sample Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td><td>Sample Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td><td>Sample Data</td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="myDiv2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td><td>Sample Data</td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>2</td><td>Sample Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td><td>Sample Data</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td><td>Sample Data</td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Felix gave a very good solution. But, I would suggest you not to use this approach anywhere. It might give you unexpected results. Better way is to set some data properties and than use them to delete the associated tables. This way you will have total control over what table gets emptied.

**HTML**

```
<a class="emptytable" id="Tele" data-table="#table-1">Empty table 1</a>
<a class="emptytable" id="Tele" data-table="#table-2">Empty table 2</a>
...

<table id="table-1">...</table>
<table id="table-2">...</table>
...
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('.emptytable').click(function(){
        $($(this).data('table')).empty();
    });
})
```